# Pdflatex refuses to process .bib file with hash sign #

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, texlive, bbl

Pdflatex (not Biber) complains in the `howpublished` line in the bbl about the hastag sign. It does compile when I delete the hastag, but whats wrong, how to prevent this in the first place?

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewValue. ...s://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3168#page-11}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
%   BCOR=20mm
]{scrbook}
%\KOMAoptions{appendixprefix=true}
%
%NOTE Packages, my Macros und Formatdefinitions
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % Multilingual support -> ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Allows different font encodings and hyphenation -> ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Translates input encodings into LaTeX internal language

\usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[                % stuff in case of biber: .bib file, style etc.
    backend=biber,      
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
        \addbibresource{Literatur_utf8.bib}                     
        \defbibfilter{papers}{  type=article or type=book}  % Can seperate books/eBooks and links

\begin{document}
    This is the mwe \cite{Floyd_undated-cb}
\end{document}
```

This is the entry:

```
\entry{Floyd_undated-cb}{misc}{}
  \name{author}{3}{}{%
    {{hash=bcb66fc187ba17e78c6c22747197aecf}{%
       family={Floyd},
       family_i={F\bibinitperiod},
       given={Sally},
       given_i={S\bibinitperiod}}}%
    {{hash=e1587d1fc53e04bb032d1278b592db58}{%
       family={Ramakrishnan},
       family_i={R\bibinitperiod},
       given={K\bibnamedelima K},
       given_i={K\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim K\bibinitperiod}}}%
    {{hash=88b8fe0624f2fc41889533817e5d5b7e}{%
       family={Black},
       family_i={B\bibinitperiod},
       given={David\bibnamedelima L},
       given_i={D\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim L\bibinitperiod}}}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{ec7a91f3f202ddfd3328bffa83be3444}
  \strng{fullhash}{ec7a91f3f202ddfd3328bffa83be3444}
  \field{sortinit}{F}
  \field{sortinithash}{c6a7d9913bbd7b20ea954441c0460b78}
  \field{labelnamesource}{author}
  \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
  \field{howpublished}{\url{https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3168#page-11}}
  \field{title}{The Addition of Explicit Congestion Notification ({ECN}) to {IP}}
  \verb{url}
  \verb https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3168#page-11
  \endverb
  \keyw{bibliography\_bsc}
\endentry
```

Biber version:

```
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.sty
Package: biblatex_ 2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/A
B)
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, please note though that the code is next to useless for us since we don't have you `.bib` file, so we will still have to type that up ourselves. See [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) for hints on MWEs for bibliography questions.

Comment: Please post the entry from the bib file, not the one from the bbl file.

Comment: It can't work. The url with the # is in the argument of another command (`\field`) and so can't change the catcodes. Beside this: You have the same url already in the url field (where it works) so why did you add it to howpublished a second time?

Comment: @AndrewSwann: The url *is* wrapped in a \url command. See `\field{howpublished}{\url{https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3168#page-11}} ` but in biblatex this doesn't help. url's with special chars must go in verbatim fields.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for pointing that out - I clearly didn't test enough.  So do we need a solution via `\urldef`?

Comment: Your `url` is in the wrong field: it should be as a `url` in the `.bib` file, not in `howublished`. The `url` field is handled verbatim, `howpublsihed` is not.

Comment: Why does it work fine in the \verb field but not in `howpublished`, oh ok its the dedicated verb field, (just saw the answer)

Comment: @ItsmeJulian You can't generally put `\verb` inside other macro arguments. So in the `.bbl`  the set up for verbatim fields is different from other fields (which can be handed just as simple arguments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have an unescaped hash sign in non-verbatim fields in your `.bib` file even if you hide it in a `\url` command, where normally it does not cause harm.

URLs should best be given in the dedicated `url` field (which you seem to have done anyway), which can handle evil characters such as `#` and friends, because it uses a special verbatim mode.

You can then delete the `howpublished` with Biber's sourcemapping before it causes any harm. We can even try and recover the URL from the `howpsublished` field if we don't already have a `url` field.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=howpublished, match=\regexp{\A\\url\{(.+)\}\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=url, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[fieldset=howpublished, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}  

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=howpublished, match=\regexp{\A\\url\{(.+)\}\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=url, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[fieldset=howpublished, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{bronto,
  title        = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  howpublished = {\url{https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.html#page11}},
}
@misc{tric,
  title        = {A Theory on Triceratops},
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  url          = {https://example.edu/~elk/tric.html#page11},
  howpublished = {\url{https://example.edu/~elk/tric.html#page12}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{bronto,tric}             
\printbibliography                           
\end{document}
```